# What diapers are septic safe?

Tags: diaper

I have a 6-month-old. In 2 weeks I'm moving to a new house. The only problem is, the new house has a septic tank and I can't seem to find diapers that say septic-safe. Does anyone know what brand that I can use?

Comment: Is there a specific reason they have to go in the toilet and not in the trash?

Comment: I am not aware of any disposable diapers that go in either sewer or septic tanks.

Comment: @Erica Gdiapers have disposable inserts that supposedly can be flushed. Gdiapers are sort of a cross between full cloth diapering and disposables, IMO.

Comment: Yeah, I've seen them (probably would have used them for my youngest if we didn't have usable cloth diapers still!) but it wasn't what came to mind from this question. It's the most likely candidate, though.

Comment: This is off topic but it's also helpful to use yogurt and flush it  down into your septic tank every few months

Answer (score 8):

**There is no brand of diaper that is safe to flush down the toilet if you have a septic** You should not flush disposable diaper liners or wipes either, nor tampons, cotton swabs or cotton balls. Basically the only thing you should allow to enter a septic system is urine, feces, and toilet paper. Even food should not go into the system, which is why you won't find a garbage disposal in the kitchen sink of a home that has a septic. Cat litter is really bad too, and you shouldn't do 7 loads of laundry in one day either (it should be spread out over the week.) Think of it this way: if you wouldn't dump it in your backyard, you shouldn't flush it down the toilet.

If you decide to flush things that don't belong in the septic, be prepared to *at least* have it pumped more frequently than recommended, or, *at worst* to pay for costly repair/replacement to components or the system itself due to failure.

You can find tons of resources online about what you can and can't flush into a septic, so I'm not going to include links. They are easy to find and numerous.

I grew up in a house with a septic. The first one we had failed because we did all the wrong things, so, aside from online resources that will support my answer, I have personal experience with this as well.  It's a terrible terrible thing when the septic fails.

One final note-DO flush poop from a diaper down the toilet. Poop belongs in the toilet, not the landfill. Diapers belong in the landfill, not the toilet.

Comment: "DO flush poop from a diaper down the toilet" - That is not always possible, as the consistency of fecal matter varies, and for babies it will often be of the consistency that is absorbed into the lining of the diaper.

Comment: Okayyyyyy, let me clarify: DO flush *solid* poop...*solid* poop belongs in the toilet.

Answer (score 1):

There are septic safe flushable diaper liners but never heard of flushable diapers. Either way though, I would recommend not flushing anything other than the normal items (a friend had clogged her toilet with the flushable diaper liners - HUGE mess)